# Create Macro to Export All Font Colors to Text File / Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to create a macro that would essentially export all font colors used in a powerpoint presentation and list which slide(s) they exist on. The main reason is that somehow, several different shades of black / green make their way into a presentation (shades that are difficult for my colorblind eyes to differentiate), and I would like to see that called out in a list of somesort. I'm not seeing much online that would help - Any ideas?

Comment: Start by doing internet searches on terms like _PowerPoint VBA get font colors_ and _PowerPoint VBA write to text file_. When you get a code listing together and need help debugging it, post it here and we'll help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The text within a shape can have various colors setting. The code iterates through all characters to gather information about the font name and color used.

```vb
Sub ExtractFontsAndColors()
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptShape As Object
    Dim textRange As Object
    Dim outputFile As String
    Dim Object As Object
    Dim sKey
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    outputFile = "d:\temp\color.txt"
    objDic("FontName" & vbTab & "Color") = ""
    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.HasTextFrame Then
                Set textRange = pptShape.TextFrame.textRange
                For i = 1 To Len(textRange.Text)
                    With textRange.Characters(i, 1).Font
                        sKey = .Name & vbTab & .Color
                        objDic(sKey) = ""
                    End With
                Next i
            End If
        Next pptShape
    Next pptSlide
    Open outputFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, Join(objDic.Keys, vbCrLf)
    Close #1
    MsgBox "Output file: " & outputFile
End Sub
```

Output:

```
FontName    Color
Abadi   255
Abadi   0
Amasis MT Pro   14524133
```